# Sed to extract text from start to string

Tags: regex, sed

I have input like this:

```
xxxx1
xxxx2
xxxx3
END
xxxx4
xxxx5
```

I want this:

```
xxxx1
xxxx2
xxxx3
```

I tried.

```
<<input>> | sed -n '/./,/^END/p' | sed '$d'
```

But I get:

```
xxxx1
xxxx2
xxxx3
END
xxxx4
```

It seems to be the '.' that does not work here.

Comment: Not a sed user. What does this mean ? `'/./,/^END/p'`

Comment: I guess that `xxxx` can be any random thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to get all data up until `END` and `xxxx` can by anything, this `awk` should do:

```
<<input>> | awk '/END/ {exit} 1'
xxxx1
xxxx2
xxxx3
```

- If `END` is found, exit
- `1` always true, and since no action, do the default action, print

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^END$/Q' file
```

Print all lines until a line containing `END` only, then quit.

Alternative:

```
sed -n '/^END$/q;p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `awk`.

```
 awk '/^xxxx/{f=1}/^END/{f=0;exit}{ if (f!=0){print $0}}' file
```

**output**

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

the `f=1` sets a flag to indicate the starting value has been found. As long as that flag value is set, (which we test with) 
`if (f!=0)`, we print the current line of input. When the terminating value `/^END/` is found, the variable is unset, and we have to exit, because, in this case the starting value will be found again, and it will be printed.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

With POSIX sed:

`sed '/^END/,$d'`

or

`sed -n '1,/^END/{/^END/!p}'`