# Parsing and creating new arguments with getline AWK code

Tags: awk

I am writing a pretty long AWK program (NOT terminal script) to parse through a network trace file. I have a situation where the next line in the trace file is ALWAYS a certain type of 'receive' (3 possible types) - however, I only want AWK to handle/print on one type. In short, I want to tell AWK if the next line contains a certain receive type, do not include it. It is my understanding that `getline` is the best way to go about this.

I have tried a couple different variations of `getline` and `getline VAR` via the manual, I still cannot seem to search through and reference fields in the next line like I want. Updated from edit:

```
    if ((event=="r") && (hopSource == hopDest)) {        
        getline x
        if ((x $31 =="arp") || (x $35 =="AODV")) {
            #printf("Badline %s %s \n", $31, $35) 
        }
        else {
            macLinkRec++;
            #printf("MAC Link Recieved from HEAD - %d to MEMBER %d \n", messageSource, messageDest)
        }
    }
```

I am using the `print(badline)` as just a marker to see what is going on. I fully understand how to restructure the code once I get the search and reference correct. I am also able to print the correct 'next' lines. However, I would expect to be able to search through the next line and create new arguments based on what is contained in the next line. How do I search a 'next line' based on an argument in AWK? How do I reference fields in that line to create new arguments?

Final note, the 'next line' number of fields (NF) varies, but I feel that the `$35` field reference should handle any problems there.

Comment: What do you mean with the statements `(getline $31=="arp")` or `(x $31=="arp")`. It is not clear what you intend to do here, but I can assure you that it is wrong.

Comment: I am attempting to reference field 31 on the next line. If field 31 contains either of those strings, print badline.

Comment: Also `print` is not a function, it is an awk keyword, so the notation `print("badline")` is better written as `print "badline"`. The above works because the brackets `( expr )` is a grouping.

Comment: And if you retrieved the next line with `getline`, do you want your awk program to reprocess it in the next full cycle?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by 'reprocess it in the next full cycle'. I want it to 're-getline' the next time the main ```if ((event=="r") && (hopSource == hopDest)) {``` holds true and refer to that new line's next line.

Comment: When you just do `getline`, you will overwrite your record `$0` with the new value. And thus, any field-references from that point forward will always refer to the new record. The previous is lost. If you do `getline var`, you will keep the original record, but the next line will stored in `var`. That particular line will never be processed again by awk or any of its actions and field-references. So my question is, which of the behaviours would you like?

Comment: Alway refer to the new record.

Comment: After the `printf` statement do, `getline`. Then remove the `getline`'s from the if condition.

Comment: Okay - see the updated edit. I see more so about what you are talking about that it will forever change the next line. (I get other parts of the program that were referring the same line changing). How do you go about removing it from the loop where it will still work on the next possible iteration?

Comment: There is a multitude of possibilities, but everything depends a bit on how the full script looks like. Is it possible to post it here, or do you want a general answer? That is to say, an answer that always works but that is fairly inefficient.

Comment: there are FAQs about "why not to use getline in awk", you might want to check those out. AND your Q seems amenable to a "flag" variable solution. Check out my super-simple flag program for a different problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548670/620097 . There are a lot of `awk` answers here that use this technique, but they are hard to find, because the variable name used for the flag can be any variable name and "flag variable solution" is my terminology, although some answers will refer to flag variables. Good luck!